# Airflow trigger rules for 2 parents with one_success - Can the worker be run after EACH parent's success?

Tags: airflow

I sounds like A >> [ B, C ] >> D
where D is one_success triggered
would only run D once.

Is there a way I can get D to be run after each success (instead of waiting for both)

Or do I have to set up two different DAGs ?
A >> B >> D
and
A >> C >> D

And regardless of the answer
..and then since D is not runnable in parallel, I assume I should assign D to a specific pool
where the pool only has one worker slot

Thanks !

Anyone have good complex triggering experience ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have two different DAGs. You do need two operators for D.
This should solve the issue without using pools:

```
with DAG(
   dag_id="my_dag",
   default_args={'owner': 'airflow'},
   start_date=datetime(2020, 12, 9),
   schedule_interval=None,
) as dag:

    A = DummyOperator(
        task_id='A_task')

    B = DummyOperator(
        task_id='B_task')

    C = DummyOperator(
        task_id='C_task')

    D1 = DummyOperator(
        task_id='D1_task',
        trigger_rule='one_success')

    D2 = DummyOperator(
        task_id='D2_task')

    A >> [B, C] >> D1
    [B, C] >> D2
    D1 >> D2
```

[image]

**Explnation:**

`D1` will kick only once either `B` or `C` will be in success status.

`D2` will kick only when `B` & `C` & `D1` will be in success mode thus:

- `D2` & `D1` can't run in parallel.
- `D2` will kick in only after the "2nd success" of `B` & `C` regardless if `B` finished before or after `C`.

Comment: That's cool.  May I ask a related question then about avoiding parallelism.  If I don't want to wait for this DAG to finish before it kicks off another one, how to I keep A B C D1 and D2 from running in parellel if a second instatiation of the DAG kicks off.  Would I put a pool for A, one for B, one for C, and one for D1 and D2, and make sure each of those only has one worker slot, or what is the way to stop any worker from running in parallel ?  Many thanks

Comment: @DataGuy are you referring to a case that max_active_runs > 1 ?